# If a sequence converges, but not uniformly converges to 0, can its corresponding series converge uniformly?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

I was wondering about how one can prove a series is not uniformly convergent, and this came accross my mind. Can anyone explain this in real numbers as well as complex numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$|a_n(x)| = \left|\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k(x) - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}a_k(x)\right|$$

shows that uniform convergence of the sequence is necessary for uniform convergence of the series (by the Cauchy criterion).

Answer (score 1):

Because if $S_n(x)$ is the sequence of partial sums of $f_n(x)$ and it converges uniformly to the function $S(x)$ then $f_n(x)=S_n(x)-S_{n-1}(x)\to S(x)-S(x)=0$ uniformly. We just use the fact that the sum of two uniformly convergent sequences converges uniformly to the sum function. This proof works in both real and complex analysis.